# Apply custom css for user role

Tags: css, admin-css

How can I apply custom CSS for user role, both for dashboard and frontend? For dashboard I set:

```
if( current_user_can('seller', 'partner')) { 
    function admin_style() {
  wp_enqueue_style('admin-styles', get_template_directory_uri().'/admin.css');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_style');
}
   else {

}
```

how to modify the code to load also on front? btw, Is `if( current_user_can('seller', 'partner'))` correct for checking is user role is `seller` and `partner`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enqueue CSS in WordPress you can use:

- `wp_enqueue_scripts` action for the frontend
- `login_scripts` action for the login page
- `admin_scripts`action for the admin side, as you already know

To check user's roles you should get the user object and check the roles property. `current_user_can()` is function intended to check capabilities, not roles.

So, to add CSS based on user roles in the frontend:

```
add_action( 'enqueue_scripts', 'cyb_enqueue_styles' );
function cyb_enqueue_styles() {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( ! empty( $user ) && count( array_intersect( [ "seller", "partner" ], (array) $user->roles ) ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/some-style.css' );
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I check if one user has one particular role and doesn't have another using the same logic? In this case to check if user is partner but is not seller? Thank you for answer!

Comment: What problem do you have to do It? I don't undersntand you. In the answer you can see how to get the current user roles, checking if the user has or has not some role should be trivial, can you explain deeper the problem you have?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the whole answer. Everything is fine now. Thank you